# WS Play Framework - How send File with post

Tags: file, upload, playframework-2.4

I read this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS but I Can't figure aout how can I send post data + file.

Example:
I want use this API https://code.google.com/p/imagebam-api/wiki/UploadImage to upload image but I dont know how. I tryed this :

```
val file:File = new File("c:/file/sample.jpg")

   val postMap = Map(
      "oauth_consumer_key"      -> Seq(apiKey.toString),
      "oauth_signature_method"  -> Seq(oauthSignatureMethod.toString),
      "oauth_signature"         -> Seq(oauthSignature.toString),
      "oauth_timestamp"         -> Seq(oauthTimestAmp.toString),
      "oauth_nonce"             -> Seq(oauthNonce.toString),
      "oauth_token"             -> Seq(oauthToken.toString),
      "content_type"            -> Seq("adult"),
      "thumb_format"            -> Seq("JPG"),
      "thumb_size"              -> Seq("350x350"),
      "thumb_cropping"          -> Seq(0.toString),
      "thumb_info"              -> Seq(1.toString),
      "response_format"         -> Seq("JSON"),
      "image"                   -> Seq(file)
    )

    val bb_SendImg = WS.url("http://www.imagebam.com/sys/API/resource/upload_image").post(postMap)
```

but this dosn't work. Any sugestion or help how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't post a multipartform-data with play WS.

It's one of the oldest [improvement request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/902) in the bug tracker.

There is some workarounds exposed in this issue. You can use [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http#post-multipartform-data) for example.